# PHP SQLITE PDO Check if views OR table exist

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I have, apparently, a simple question. As a documentation I can check if TABLE OR VIEWS exist on DataBase. In my app i need to check if both allready existe in db for return custom error. the problem is that I can check if there is a TABLE, but NOT the VIEWS. ex:

```
 **Working case**
 $checkTable = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name  ='$table' and type='table'", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

 **Not working case**
 $checkTable = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name  ='$table' and type='table' OR type='views'", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

**Not working case**
 $checkTable = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name  ='$table' and type='views'", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The strange thing is that if I run a query on the views, this returns the results:

```
**Working case**
 $checkTable = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM VIEWSpeople WHERE name   ='$person'", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

general query on sqlite_master find the views:

```
 **Working case**
 $checkTable = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name   ='$table'", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

question: why the query does not recognize the views as type='views'?
thanks for your time.

Comment: would it not be just `view` rather than `views`?

Comment: HI RRAider and thank you, I tried also "VIEW" nothing good

Answer (score 0):

The type of a view is not `views` but `view`.

Additionally, you should use parentheses to ensure that the expressions are evaluated in the correct order:

```sql
... WHERE name ='$table' AND (type='table' OR type='view')
```

Alternatively, use IN:

```sql
... WHERE name ='$table' AND type IN ('table', 'view')
```

Comment: Hi CL and thank you for your help. But:
 $checkTable = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name ='$table' AND type IN ('table', 'view')", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
NO RESULT. And
$checkTable = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name ='$table' AND (type='table' OR type='view')", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
NO RESULT. Any Idea?